# What are the different methods to join 2 parts so that one can rotate 180 degrees around the other?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, machine-design, machine-elements

Let's say we have one simple box and its bottom has been cut in a circular shape. We want to attach another box to this box that can rotate 180deg around the first one. What mechanism can be used to join these two boxes?

Comment: A groove which defines the end points and a locating pin.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps a "turntable bearing" also called a "lazy susan" bearing. Something like this one: [https://www.amazon.com/Square-Inch-Susan-Turntable-Bearing/dp/B00ZSQSWTM](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00ZSQSWTM)